# Angular JS Error: No module detected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

I'm starting work on a members section of my website, using AngularJS.

**v0.1.0.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?php echo ucfirst($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']); ?>'s dashboard</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="usr" ng-controller="userControll as users" ng-init=<?php echo "'users.setUser(" . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] .")'"?>><!-- since I'm using server auth, to transfer to angular-->
        <div style="background-color: #000000; color: #c0c0c0;">
              <div class="container">
                    <img ng-src="{{users.user.icon}}" alt="avatar" />
                    <h1>{{users.user.name}}</h1>
                    <i>@<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']; ?></i>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
              <h1>Dashboard</h1>
              <!--Nav tabs-->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home"><h1>Home</h1><br>{{users.user.data}}</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
                          <h2>{{users.user.name}}</h2>
                          <hr>
                          <span style="color: gray">Coming soon</span>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">
                          <h2>Settings</h2>
                          <span style="color: gray">Coming soon</span>
                          <hr>
                          <h3>About</h3>
                          <i>v0.1.0<br>&copy; Imagifight Studios 2015</i>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('usr', []);
  var userData = $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url:'user-data.json'
  })
  .done(function(data) {
        $.each(function(data){
              $.parseJSON(data);
        });
  }).fail(console.error('Damn. Didn\'t work.'));

  app.controller('userControll', function(){
        this.setUser = function(u){
              this.user = userData[u];
        }
  })
})();
```

**user-data.json**

```
{
  "imagifight": {
        "name": "Imagifight",
        "email": "imagifight@gmail.com",
        "status": "owner",
        "icon": "icons/imagifight.png"
  }
}
```

Throws error:

> Damn.Didnt work
>   (anonymous function)   @   app.js:11

Can't see where the ajax went wrong. No syntax errors either. Maybe I'm missing something here, I don't know. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: fail gives an error msg or code .. to tell y the ajax failed.. try `.fail(console.log);` or `.fail(console.error);`

Comment: Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yL6gh1fq/)

Comment: Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkqw9qqx/3/). there is a bit of problem in what you are trying to achieve.. though I have done it by some dirty hack you can see it from the code

Comment: for `url:` do I do `url: 'user-data.json'` or `url: 'http://www.imagifight.in/usr/user-data.json'`?

Comment: either of them will do.. if the user-data.json is in the same directory you can do `url: 'user-data.json'` .. both will do...

Comment: Hey I found another solution.. :) if you want it here is the js [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkqw9qqx/7/)

Comment: I'm well and thoroughly stumped

Comment: you can check they are retrieving data from a `json` provider

Comment: so there must be some problem with your json provider

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95455/discussion-between-minato-and-imagifight).

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with Quote. Escape it as

```
console.error('Damn. Didn\'t work.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ' inside the console error.

Change: `console.error('Damn. Didn't work.')`

To: `console.error('Damn. Didn\'t work.')`

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to escape it here. I'd done that in my code.